# try to insert a json string with wpdb

Tags: php, json, wordpress, insert

this is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$location.",de&lang=de&APPID=abc");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); //JSON string
curl_close($ch);

//json_decode($output);
//serialize($output);

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'dmd_weather';
$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
        'type' => 'wetter',
        'key' => $location, //<- normal string
        'value' => $output //<- json string
    )
);
```

I can't insert data with my query above.

If I change the var `$output` like `$output = 1` it works perfect. But not with a json string.

Is there a trick to insert json strings into a database with wordpress?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The field in my database was only a varchar(255).

That is not enough for my json string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape json or serialized string while inserted json string into database from wordpress like below..

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$location.",de&lang=de&APPID=abc");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); //JSON string
curl_close($ch);

//json_decode($output);
//serialize($output);

$final_output = mysql_real_escape_string($output); //<- final escaped string

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'dmd_weather';
$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
        'type' => 'wetter',
        'key' => $location, //<- normal string
        'value' => $final_output //<- json string
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysql_real_escape_string` function to escape the characters before storing them into the database.

```
$output = mysql_real_escape_string($output);
```

Comment: Can you please add following lines on the top of your script to see the actual error: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: I found the problem.

The field in my database was only a varchar(255).